# error CS1061 in Unity (C#) ; I want to change sprite in script

Tags: c#

I'm going to make a system that changes skin in the game.
Whenever I press the button, I try to change the skin sample image to the specified image (on the inspector), but there is an error.

"error CS1061: 'Sprite' does not contain a definition for 'sample' and no accessible extension method 'sample' accepting a first argument of type 'Sprite' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I don't know why I get this error even though I first designated sample as Sprite.
Help me please.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Serializable]
public class Samples
{
    public Sprite sample;
}



[System.Serializable]
public class Changes
{
    [TextArea]
    public string changes;

}

[System.Serializable]
public class Skin
{
    [TextArea]
    public string name;
    public string explain;

}

public class change_skin : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer sprite_sample;
    [SerializeField] private Text txt_changes;
    [SerializeField] private Text txt_skin_name;
    [SerializeField] private Text txt_skin_explain;

    private int count = 0;
    private int num = 0;


    [SerializeField] private Changes[] change_thing;

    [SerializeField] private Skin[] skins;


    [SerializeField]
    public Samples[] sample_image;

    [Serializable]
    public struct Samples
    {
        [SerializeField]
        public Sprite[] sample_thing;
    }

void Start()
    {
        sprite_sample.sprite = sample_image[count].sample_thing[num].**sample**;
        txt_changes.text = change_thing[num].changes;
        txt_skin_name.text = skins[count].name;
        txt_skin_explain.text = skins[count].explain;
    }
   public void bt_changes_right()
    {
        if (num >= change_thing.Length)
        {
            num = 0;
        }
        
        num++;

        txt_changes.text = change_thing[num].changes;
        sprite_sample.sprite = sample_image[count].sample_thing[num].**sample**;


    }
```

Comment: `sample_thing` is an array of `Sprite`, not of `Samples`.

Comment: `sample_thing[num]` is a `Sprite` already - why are you trying to use the `sample` field which is in `Samples`, not `Sprite`?

Comment: then should I rewrite it like this?
sprite_sample.sprite = sample_image[count].sample_thing[num]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample_thing is a Sprite, and I think you are trying to acess sample inside the Sprite object with this:
`sprite_sample.sprite = sample_image[count].sample_thing[num].**sample**;`

Try stop on sample_thing. like that:

`sprite_sample.sprite = sample_image[count].sample_thing[num];`

See whats happens if you change it from Start() and from bt_changes_right()